# Как получить ip адрес сервера на котором выполняются таски?

Tags: linux, ansible

У меня есть такой файл со список серверов:

```
192.168.77.101 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant zookeeperId=1 kafkaBrokerId=1
192.168.77.102 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant zookeeperId=2 kafkaBrokerId=2
192.168.77.103 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant zookeeperId=3 kafkaBrokerId=3
```

В одном из тасков я работаю с шаблоном c такой строчкой:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}:9092
```

Моя переменная преобразуется в список, который разделен запятыми. Как мне получить ip адрес текущего сервиса из начальных переменных?

Comment: `{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0] }}`? Типа нулевой элемент в списке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблонах используется так:

{{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}